# Best solution for reusing existing user identities for mobile app authentication

Tags: authentication, mobile, identity, mobile-application

We have an established web-based platform with a few thousand users on, who authenticate using username and password.

We're now extending the offering to include a React Native app, that will be available to anyone with a valid account in our platform. We're currently working on the app.

I'm looking for a low-friction secure solution to allow users to authenticate in the mobile app using their existing web platform identity. What we don't want is username and password login for day-to-day use of the app.

We are also building an api that will serve content to the app - initially this content will be generic (not user-specific) so I anticipate that mobile app will authenticate itself with a bearer token to pull this content.

What would be considered an industry-standard solution to this challenge? I'm not against users perhaps having to provide username and password during setup (although I'd prefer to avoid it if possible), but after that we'd like identity to be tied to the device if this can be done securely.

It should also be mentioned that later in the year, additional web-based platforms under our control may also look to use the same identities to authenticate and authorise.

During later iterations, the private data available via the app will be of a sensitive nature, so the solution we land on now must be strong enough further down the line. Or at least open to strengthening.

We're not assuming we will build the identity management ourselves, either. If it's relatively simple, we could. But it feels to me like a cloud-based service might actually be what we need here.